# Iterate through array of objects shows syntax error reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am rendering the unordered list elements based on array of objects. Here is my list array return inside `this.state`.

```
this.state = {
      cards: [{name: "card1", id: 1}, {name: "card2", id: 2}, {name: "card3", id: 3}]
    };
```

Using `render()` i will be listing the list elements.

```
render() {
    return ( <ul>
        this.state.cards.map((card) => { 
          return <li>{card.name}</li> 
        });
      </ul>
    )
  }
```

`Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Cards.js: Unexpected token (26:41)`. So the error is exactly at this point.[image]

Comment: Interestingly your error snapshot shows that you are using `->` sign for an arrow function while the code snippet is using correct `=>` sign

Answer (score 3):

You just need to wrap your js code in curly braces

```
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {this.state.cards.map((card) => { 
        return <li>{card.name}</li>
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put *curly braces* when you want to use the value of a variable inside `HTML`.

The curly braces are a special syntax to let the `JSX` parser know that it needs to interpret the contents in between them as `JavaScript` instead of a *string*.

In your case like this:

```
render() {
    return ( 
      <ul>
        {this.state.cards.map(card => <li>{card.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    );
}
```

My approach:

```
render = () => {
   const { cards } = this.state; // Destructuring assignment  
   const cardsDraw = cards.map(x => <li key={x.id}>{x.name}</li>);
 return (
   <ul>
     {cardsDraw}
   </ul>
  );
};
```